# React native - Image Upload : Node Post API not getting called with fetch

Tags: node.js, react-native, fetch, expo, image-upload

I am trying to post the image selected by the user to the node js API using fetch. But for some reason the API post method is not getting called while the same works with Postman.

This is occurring when running the solution within the Expo app. To eliminate the possibility of localhost being the culprit, have made use of ngrok https url for posting the request.

Also, tried to set content-type to undefined/null/multipart/form-data but nothing seems to help reach the Post API call.

```
const createFormData = (photo, body) => 
{
  const data = new FormData();

  data.append("photo", {
  name: photo.fileName,
  type: photo.type,
  uri:
     Platform.OS === "android" ? 
     photo.uri 
     : photo.uri.replace("file://", "")
    });


Object.keys(body).forEach(key => {
   data.append(key, body[key]);
});

  return data;
};


handleUploadPhoto = () => {

  fetch("http://ngrok:3000/api/upload", 
  {
     method: "POST",
     headers: { "Content-Type" : 
                "multipart/form-data", 
                "Accept": 
                "application/json"},
     body: 
        createFormData(this.state.photo, 
        { userId: "123" })
   });
 };
```

When the above code runs, the application doesn't throw an error but doesn't seem to make a post request too.

Comment: Why are you adding body as a parameter and not using it? Am I missing something

Comment: Body has a parameter besides it.                                 
                                                                                           body:  createFormData(this.state.photo, { userId: "123" })

Comment: no I mean in the method `createFormData` you passed a parameter called body and didn't use it

Comment: Oh !! I didn't add that part because the code would go lengthy here. But ya, have added it now.